# find the version of a gem install in system programatically

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, passenger

I am trying to get the version of a gem in the system through Rails code in the initializers.

The issue is I have latest version cached in my application/vendor/cache directory and older version is installed in the system 
I am trying to find the version of the gem installed in the system, but when I run "gem search gemname" it always gives me the version in cache

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
gem list gem_name
```

This command will give you all the versions installed in your system.

Comment: This does not work when I am doing it from my rails env. It gives me the gem version listed in the gemfile

Answer (score 0):

To get a detailed description of the gems ( including location which you seem to be looking for ) do this `gem list -d gemname`.  For your bundled gems just put a `bundle exec` in front of previous command.